# Choose an Amazon Machine image[AMI] for Integrating with cpanel [centOS]

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpanel, amazon-ami

We are using Amazon web service.

Which AMI we have to choose for Installing "Cpanel" with "Centos"

please inform us about which AMI, Virtualisation type, & bit for integrating Cpanel with AWS.

please guide me about this.